# Imprimir Varios Datos en C++

Tags: c++

Buenos Días, tengo el siguiente ejercicio en el que deseo que al final del programa me arroje una lista con los nombres y cédula de los que son extranjeros. Como puedo hacerlo?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    /*3. Desarrolle un programa en C++ que lea el nombre y la nacionalidad 
    18 pasajeros, e imprima los datos de los pasajeros 
    con nacionalidad no venezolana. Utilice ciclo For*/

    char nom[10], nac;
    int ve=0,ex=0, n=0,c;

    system("color A");

    for (n=1;n<=2;n++)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Seleccione su Nacionalidad: \n";
        cout<<" A: Extranjero\n";
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<" B: Venezolano\n";
        cin>>nac;
        cout<<endl;

        switch(nac)
        {
        case 'a': case 'A':
            cout<<" "<<n<<") Ingrese su nombre: ";
            cin>>nom;
            ex++;
            cout<<"\nIngrese su Cedula: ";
            cin>>c;

            break;

        case 'b': case 'B' :
            cout<<" "<<n<<") Ingrese su nombre: ";
            cin>>nom;
            ve++;
            cout<<"\nIngrese su Cedula: ";
            cin>>c;

            break;

        default:
            cout<<" Opcion no valida";
            cout<<endl;
            n--;
        } 

    }

    system("cls");
    cout<<"\nNumero de Extranjeros: "<<ex;
    cout<<"\nNumero de Venezolanos: "<<ve;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque ya te han contestado aquí va una manera más, algo mas básica que la de nuestro compañero PaperBirdMaster.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 /*3. Desarrolle un programa en C++ que lea el nombre y la nacionalidad
 18 pasajeros, e imprima los datos de los pasajeros
 con nacionalidad no venezolana. Utilice ciclo For*/
```

**Creo tres vectores, donde guardo de forma paralela el nombre, la nacionalidad y cédula de cada persona.**

```
 char nom[18][10];//Pese a esto, te recomiendo utilizar el tipo string
 para no limitar la cantidad de caracteres, codificando algo asi: string nom[18];

 char nac[18];
 int c[18];
 int ve=0,ex=0;


 for (int i=0;i<18;i++)
{
system("cls");
cout<<"Seleccione su Nacionalidad: \n";
cout<<" A: Extranjero";
cout<<endl;
cout<<" B: Venezolano\n";
cin>>nac[i];
cout<<endl;

switch(nac[i])
{
case 'A':case 'a':
    cout<<" "<<") Ingrese su nombre: ";
    cin>>nom[i];
    nac[i]='A';ex++;//Guarda nacionalidad en el espacio i de un array
    cout<<"\nIngrese su Cedula: ";
    cin>>c[i];//Guarda nacionalidad en el espacio i de un array

    break;

case 'B':case 'b':
    cout<<" "<<") Ingrese su nombre: ";
    cin>>nom[i];
    nac[i]='B';ve++;
    cout<<"\nIngrese su Cedula: ";
    cin>>c[i];

    break;

default:
    cout<<" Opcion no valida";
    cout<<endl;i--;
}


}

system("cls");
cout<<"\nNumero de Extranjeros: "<<ex;
cout<<"\nNumero de Venezolanos: "<<ve;
```

**Usamos un bucle para recorres el array de nacionalidad y cuando el carácter que hay en la posición i es A, muestra el contenido de la misma posición del resto de arrays.**

```
for(int i=0;i<18;i++)
  {
if(nac[i]=='A')
{
    cout<<endl<<"Nombre: "<<nom[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"Cedula: "<<c[i]<<endl;
 }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aunque válida, no suele ser buena práctica mantener los datos relacionados en sitios diferentes... mantener la integridad relacional de tres vectores puede llegar a ser bastante complicado

Comment: Para el nombre, la mejor opción (en mi opinión) sería usar `std::string`, pues no limita el nombre a 17 letras... ¿Qué pasaría si ingresan en el sistema a un tal "*Alfredo Atanagildo Turismundo de todos los Santos*"?

Comment: @eferion Es muy cierto lo que dices, pero cuando empiezas es mas fácil manipular información entre arrays en diferentes sitios, que comprender y realizar enums, estructuras y demás. Probablemente lo que el intentaba realizar en un principio se acerca más a mi respuesta. #PaperBirdMaster Estoy totalmente de acuerdo, pero continuando con la idea que el tenia, decidí dejar el array de caracteres que usaba él. Pero si es cierto que es mucho mas recomendable usar un string, lo editare.

Comment: Cual seria la Sintaxis correcta al utilizar el String? Lo declaro arriba como string nombre[18][30] pero el "cin>>" no lo reconoce, con cual se sustituye?

Answer (score 5):

> Deseo que al final del programa me arroje una lista con los nombres y cédula de los que son extranjeros. Como puedo hacerlo?

Guarda los datos en una lista al finalizar la recolección de datos, recorre la lista imprimiendo sólo aquellos que coincidan con el criterio que necesitas para imprimir.

Por ejemplo, teniendo una clase `persona`:

```
enum class nacionalidad : int
{
    Venezuela,
    Extranjera,
};

struct persona
{
    nacionalidad nacionalidad;
    std::string nombre;
    int cedula;
};
```

Y una lista de personas:

```
using personas = std::list<persona>;

personas p
{
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, "A", 0 },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, "B", 1 },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, "C", 2 },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, "D", 3 },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, "E", 4 },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, "F", 5 },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, "G", 6 },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, "H", 7 },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, "I", 8 },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, "J", 9 },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, "K", 0 },
};
```

Podemos imprimir las que son `Extranjera` de la siguiente manera:

```
std::for_each(p.begin(), p.end(), [](auto &p)
{
    if (p.nacionalidad == nacionalidad::Extranjera) std::cout << p.nombre << '\n';
});
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oUzBZTzkiORcycoB)</kbd>.

---

También es posible aprovechar los contenedores que agrupan datos por tipo para facilitar esta operación, si creamos un multimapa que clasifique por nacionalidad:

```
#include <map>

enum class nacionalidad : int
{
    Venezuela,
    Extranjera,
};

struct persona
{
    std::string nombre;
    int cedula;
};

using personas = std::multimap<nacionalidad, persona>;
```

Podemos seleccionar una nacionalidad concreta con [`equal_range`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range):

```
personas p
{
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, {"A", 0} },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, {"B", 1} },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, {"C", 2} },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, {"D", 3} },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, {"E", 4} },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, {"F", 5} },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, {"G", 6} },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, {"H", 7} },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, {"I", 8} },
    { nacionalidad::Extranjera, {"J", 9} },
    { nacionalidad::Venezuela, {"K", 0} },
};

const auto &personas_extranjeras = p.equal_range(nacionalidad::Extranjera);

for (auto p = personas_extranjeras.first; p != personas_extranjeras.second; ++p)
{
    std::cout << p->second.nombre << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lYVNSmo4QOcqzwfL)</kbd>.

Comment: Dado que no ha etiquetado C++11 o superior quizás estaría bien presentar una solución sin elementos propios de los últimos estándares

Comment: Es cierto, pero me cuesta entender la pregunta así que de momento lo dejo así. No te cortes a la hora de aportar tu solución :)

Comment: Sería demasiado parecida a la tuya pero sin lambdas, listas de inicialización, using, ... no se si merece la pena... lo más destacable es que usaría `vector` en vez de `list`... o quizás un multimapa.

Comment: Use `list` porque en la respuesta escribí *lista*, pero mi elección sería un `vector` también :)

Comment: Con un multimarca podrías usar `lower_bounds` y `upper_bounds` para quedarte con el rango que te interesa imprimir...

Comment: Me encantaría ver otra opción y aprender de ella, si no es molestia.